# Data comparison in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, date, laravel-5

I'm beginner in laravel and I'm trying to run comparison queries given in the database.
I saved a field date that is implemented by a form together with other fields including the name.
I tried to query the name and it works all regularly with this code below.

I would like to retrieve all the rows that have the name variable as the field name that I pass (and here it seems to work) and then only those with the field date that have the specified month at the number that I pass as variable $month.
what would be the right form to do this?
thanks
Piero

```
public function filterparamenter(){
      $name = request('name');
      $month = request('$month');
      $query = subagente::all();
      $query = $query->where('subagente', $subagente);
      $query = $query->whereMonth('data', $month)->get();
```

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::whereMonth does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `::all()` returns a `Collection`, which has a `->where()` method, but `->whereMonth()` is only available on Eloquent's `Builder` class. Change your code as follows:

```
$query = subagente::query();
$query = $query->where('subagente', $subagente);
$query = $query->whereMonth('data', $month)->get();
```

Or, more compact:

```
$results = subagente::where("subagente", $subagente)
->whereMonth("data", $month)
-get();
```

Using `::query()` or `::where()` to start your query will generate a `Builder` instance, which you can chain addition clauses (`->where()`, `->whereMonth()`, etc) on before calling `->get()` to return a `Collection` of `subagente` records.

Side note, should `"data"` be `"date"`?

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I did not know that I could create a new instance. Regarding the date and 'the name of the field of type date, but to avoid confusion I put it in English because I had inserted it in Italian

Comment: Ah, gotcha. No worries! But yeah, the `Builder`, which is generated from stuff like `->where()`, `->with()`, `->has()`, etc etc can chain multiple methods, but as soon as you call `->get()`, or if you start with `->all()`, it's a `Collection`, which has different methods/logic. Confusing at first, but it'll become clearer the more you work with Laravel.